# Please specify the product's option(s)

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, template, addtocart, ce-1.9.2.4

I am currently using magento 1.9.2.4 and i built the custom theme

I am using custom made configurable swatches color then I did some little hack it was working

I made custom radio button with the product super attr in array then i made size configurable now when i click on add to cart it asks me for the:

> Please specify the product option

As both are ticked I can check by dumping and **when i create product without size it works**.

Here is my whole code for colour and size as i have written custom js for colour switch

```
<h3>select a colour</h3>

<?php if ($_product->isConfigurable()): ?>
    <?php $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product) ?>
    <?php if (count($attributes)): ?>
        <?php
        $counter = 0;
        foreach ($attributes as $att): ?>
            <!--   <?php var_dump($att->debug()); ?> -->
            <?php $pAtt = $att->getProductAttribute();
            //get the child products
            // var_dump($pAtt->getAttributeCode());
            if ($pAtt->getAttributeCode() == 'color'):
                $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
                $frontValues = array() ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    $count = 1;
                    foreach ($allProducts as $p): ?>
                        <?php if (!$p->isSaleable()) continue;
                        ?>
                        <?php $out = $p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName()); ?>
                        <li>
                            <figure class="option-click swatches1" data-id="<?php echo $p->getEntityId(); ?>"
                                    data-url="<?php echo $actualImage[strtolower($out)] ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $swatches[strtolower($out)]; ?>" alt="">
                            </figure>
                            <input type="radio" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $att->getAttributeId(); ?>]"
                                   value="<?php echo $p->getColor(); ?>" <?php if ($count == 1) echo "checked"; ?>> <?php echo $out; ?>
                            <br>
                        </li>
                        <?php $counter++;
                        $count;endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($pAtt->getAttributeCode() == 'size'): ?>
                <h3>select a size</h3>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    $count = 1;
                    foreach ($allProducts as $p): ?>
                        <?php if (!$p->isSaleable()) continue;
                        ?>
                        <?php $out = $p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName()); ?>
                        <li>
                            <figure>
                                <img src="<?php echo $swatches[strtolower($out)]; ?>" alt="">
                            </figure>
                            <input type="radio" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $att->getAttributeId(); ?>]"
                                   value="<?php echo $p->getColor(); ?>" <?php if ($count == 1) echo "checked"; ?>> <?php echo $out; ?>
                            <br>
                        </li>
                        <?php $counter++;
                        $count;endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif;
        endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your problem is a simple typo.

As you said, the problem is with your size attribute as without size it works well.

And you said that Magento thinks one attribute is missing so **the size attribute is missing**.

Let's inspect your code that handles the size attribute:

```
<?php 
$count = 1;
foreach($allProducts as $p): ?>

    <?php if(!$p->isSaleable()) continue; 

    ?>

    <?php $out=$p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName()); ?>

    <li>
        <figure >
            <img src="<?php echo $swatches[strtolower($out)];  ?>" alt="">
        </figure>  
    <input type="radio" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $att->getAttributeId(); ?>]" value="<?php echo $p->getColor(); ?>" <?php if($count == 1) echo "checked"; ?>> <?php echo $out; ?><br>
    </li>
<?php $counter++; $count;endforeach; ?>
```

Notice that **your `foreach` statement is looping on a `$p` variable**.

However, your input is generated like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $att->getAttributeId(); ?>]" value="<?php echo $p->getColor(); ?>" <?php if($count == 1) echo "checked"; ?>>
```

**Instead of displaying the attribute id from `$p` you're displaying the attribute id from `$att`** which is the variable from the colour foreach loop before the size foreach loop.

On top of that you're still using `getColor` whereas it should be `getSize`

To fix your code, you need to replace the size input I pasted above with:

```
<input type="radio" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $p->getAttributeId(); ?>]" value="<?php echo $p->getSize(); ?>" <?php if($count == 1) echo "checked"; ?>>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for drawing the attension thank you +1 for the  help

Answer (score 2):

Thanks every one i sorted on my own thanks to @Raphael at Digital Pianism for drawing attention and the simple solution was

```
 <input type="radio" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $att->getAttributeId(); ?>]" value="<?php echo $p->getColor(); ?>" <?php if($count == 1) echo "checked"; ?>> <?php echo $out; ?><br>
```

i copied same code for two loops one was for colour and one was for the  size and i didnt change the `value="<?php echo $p->getColor(); ?>` to the `value="<?php echo $p->getSize(); ?>`

```
 <input type="radio" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $att->getAttributeId(); ?>]" value="<?php echo $p->getSize(); ?>" <?php if($count == 1) echo "checked"; ?>> <?php echo $out; ?><br>
```

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted instead of duplicating it as your own answer. As a bonus, you get 2 points for accepting someone else's answer.

Comment: but i found it myself ?

Comment: Haha yeah I ended up finding out that something else was wrong I edited my answer earlier today but didn't see you found it too ^^

Comment: @ujwaldhakal. OK. It looked to me like you copied it from the other answer. Sorry. Carry on.

Comment: BTW, your solution does not work for me. Using `$att->getAttributeId()` instead of what I used in my answer `$p->getAttributeId()` breaks the add to cart.

Comment: ok sir you got it but i am having strange issue nowadays  my changes are not seeing any page even though i disabled the cache setting and deleted var cache too

Answer (score 1):

A common cause of this, is that a redirect from http to https can cause the request to lose the headers containing the custom options